# In sorting quicksort if there are more than 2 same numbers..How can we sort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

If there are more than two same elements in Quicksort and pivot is also the same number...How can we sort it?
Eg: 23,19,45,21,90,5,93,45,31,45
In this array consider 45

Comment: Break the tie arbitrarily?

Comment: Try it on paper.  If you understand the algorithm you don't need a computer to run it for a small set like { 6 2 4 2 2 }.

Comment: Just try vizualization: https://visualgo.net/en/sorting

Answer (score 0):

Using Hoare like partition scheme, 45 as pivot, start with

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9    indices
23 19 45 21 90  5 93 45 31 45    data
```

scan from left for >= pivot, scan from right for <= pivot

```
      ll                   rr
23 19 45 21 90  5 93 45 31 45 
23 19 45 21 90  5 93 45 31 45    swap (both are 45, so no change)

            ll          rr 
23 19 45 21 90  5 93 45 31 45 
23 19 45 21 31  5 93 45 90 45    swap

                  ll rr
23 19 45 21 31  5 93 45 90 45
23 19 45 21 31  5 45 93 90 45    swap

                  rr ll
23 19 45 21 31  5 45 93 90 45    rr and ll crossed, rr = 6
```

The next two calls will be quicksort(0,6), quicksort(7, 9)

> How can we sort quicksort(7,9) ?

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9    indices
                     93 90 45    again assume pivot is 45

                     ll    rr
                     93 90 45
                     45 90 93    swap

                     rr ll
                     45 90 93    rr and ll crossed, rr = 7
```

The next two calls will be quicksort(7,7), quicksort(8, 9)

Comment: How can we sort quicksort(7,9)?